# OSM available data extract for addresses only?

Tags: openstreetmap, data, address

Is there a dataextract available for all addresses without the street network?

I would be interested in something like this:

```
[streetNumber, street, postcode, city, county, state, country, lat, lon]
```

I would need this because I build a custom geocoder (similar to nominatim) and would need to minimize the dataset size.

Comment: I'm not aware of such a dataset extract. If you're planning to set up a geocoder like nominatim you'll most likely use a Postgres/postgis database. Therefore, why not download the osm.pbf file (fastest one to process), extract all building, administrativ polygons, and adress features using osmosis and import these extracts into your database?

Answer (score 2):

As this question is open for 2 years now, I will post a quick & dirty reply and elaborate if further questions appear.

You can use the free software "QGIS" and the plugin "Quick OSM" to get started. This extrta will query the OSM database online and extract all data you might need. You can choose the layer you want (see on the left: "building") and leave the filter value empty. This way, Quick OSM will get all the buildings.

I did this query in less than 2 minutes and extracted most of the data you asked for (for a part of my home town). On the map, you see the greeen boxes which are the extracted buildings. You can see the table with the data belonging to the greeen boxes (buildings).

[image: Screenshot of QuickOSM and its exported data]

Comment: [@Guido Gallenkamp](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/102862/guido-gallenkamp) definitely a nice "quick & dirty" answer! However, I am thinking that [@Chris](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/57164/chris) would probably require addresses as points, not as polygons. Therefore, the solutions offered by [@zehpunktbarron](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/29308/zehpunktbarron)  has slightly more advantages and benefits towards the custom geocoder.